# Copy folders from Sharepoint by modified date

Tags: sharepoint, copy, directory

I need to create a simple program, which goes through a user-given directory on Sharepoint and finds all the folders which are older than 1 month and then it copies them to some local hard drive.
Perhaps it creates some log in a way that this folder was moved to.......

Thanks
Jakub

Comment: Hi,it is Sharepoint 2007, using windows authetication and I have nothing:) I think accessing sharepoint is no problem, I would need to find the old folders. I believe, copying them is an easiest part, but if you can help me with this whole thing, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this sample code which you can use to understand how it can be done, or you can just use it, because it seems to work fine.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MoveFolders("your_web_url", "your_doclib_url");
    }

    public static void MoveFolders(string webUrl, string listUrl)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList targetList = web.GetList(web.Url + "/" + listUrl);
                MoveFolders(targetList.RootFolder, @"C:\test"); // path to your local storage folder
            }
        }
    }

    public static void MoveFolders(SPFolder targetFolder, string rootLocalPath)
    {
        string currentPath = Path.Combine(rootLocalPath, targetFolder.Name);
        if (!Directory.Exists(currentPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(currentPath);
        DateTime lastModified = (DateTime)targetFolder.Properties["vti_timelastmodified"]; //folder last modified date
        if (lastModified < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1))
            SaveFolderLocal(targetFolder, currentPath);
        foreach (SPFolder folder in targetFolder.SubFolders)
        {
            MoveFolders(folder, currentPath);
        }
    }

    public static void SaveFolderLocal(SPFolder folder, string localStoragePath)
    {
        foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)
        {
            var contents = file.OpenBinary();
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(localStoragePath, file.Name), FileMode.Create))
            {
                fileStream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code will save your doclib folder structure locally with contents of any folder modified more than one month ago. Just be careful of using recursive MoveFolders method, because it can cause a StackOverflowException on libraries with very complex folder structure.

Comment: Thank you for that. Sorry for being such a newbie in this but I dont know how to make it work in a way that a user clicks a button and it will do the job for him as described? Also, I am not sure what is "your_web_url" and "your_doclib_url". Sorry for being such a newbie, but I am trying not to be...

Comment: site url is something like htt_p://your_sharepoint_server_name. Doclib url is usually the name of a document library. If you want a button in sharepoint site which will do this task, you could use SPContext.Current.Site instead of using (SPSite = new SPSite(..)). Just put this code on the onclick event of the button and set document library name. Please ask questions if it's still not clear.